# Is there a problem with my Negamax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to build a chess AI. My negamax function with alpha-beta pruning (ABP) runs much slower (about 8 times) than separate min and max functions also with ABP, though the moves returned are equal.

My board evaluation function always returns a value with respect to the red player, i.e. the higher the better for red. For Negamax only, this value is multiplied by -1 for the black player when returning at depth 0.

My Negamax function:

```
int alphaBeta(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (depth <= 0 || board.isGameOver()) { // game over == checkmate/stalemate
        int color = board.getCurrPlayer().getAlliance().isRed() ? 1 : -1;
        return BoardEvaluator.evaluate(board, depth) * color;
    }

    int bestVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;
    for (Move move : MoveSorter.simpleSort(board.getCurrPlayer().getLegalMoves())) {
        MoveTransition transition = board.getCurrPlayer().makeMove(move);
        if (transition.getMoveStatus().isAllowed()) { // allowed == legal && non-suicidal
            int val = -alphaBeta(transition.getNextBoard(), depth - 1, -beta, -alpha);
            if (val >= beta) {
                return val; // fail-soft
            }
            if (val > bestVal) {
                bestVal = val;
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, val);
            }
        }
    }        

    return bestVal;
}
```

The root call:

```
-alphaBeta(transition.getNextBoard(), searchDepth - 1,
                        Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE); // +1 to avoid overflow when negating
```

My min and max functions:

```
int min(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (depth <= 0 || board.isGameOver()) {
        return BoardEvaluator.evaluate(board, depth);
    }

    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Move move : MoveSorter.simpleSort(board.getCurrPlayer().getLegalMoves())) {
        MoveTransition transition = board.getCurrPlayer().makeMove(move);
        if (transition.getMoveStatus().isAllowed()) {
            minValue = Math.min(minValue, max(transition.getNextBoard(), depth - 1, alpha, beta));
            beta = Math.min(beta, minValue);
            if (alpha >= beta) break; // cutoff
        }
    }

    return minValue; 
}

int max(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (depth <= 0 || board.isGameOver()) {
        return BoardEvaluator.evaluate(board, depth);   
    }

    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Move move : MoveSorter.simpleSort(board.getCurrPlayer().getLegalMoves())) {
        MoveTransition transition = board.getCurrPlayer().makeMove(move);
        if (transition.getMoveStatus().isAllowed()) {
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, min(transition.getNextBoard(), depth - 1, alpha, beta));
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, maxValue);
            if (alpha >= beta) break; // cutoff
        }
    }

    return maxValue;
}
```

The root calls for red and black players respectively:

```
min(transition.getNextBoard(), searchDepth - 1, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
max(transition.getNextBoard(), searchDepth - 1, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

I'm guessing there's a bug with the cutoff in the Negamax function although I followed the pseudocode from [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Alpha-Beta#Outside_the_Bounds). Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: `alphaBeta()` is called about 6 times more than `min()` and `max()` combined, while the number of beta cutoffs is only about 2 times more.

Comment: Pretty sure you should not be "biasing" by color on the depth-zero return. Unless your BoardEvaluator is also doing that? (It shouldn't be.) All evaluations should be relative to red. The negations on the recursive call take care of color switch.

Comment: Take a look at this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax#Negamax_base_algorithm). The color parameter is required if the heuristic value of the node is calculated from the point of view of the red player.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I'm still thinking that the slowdown is coming from there though. That depth-zero case is all the leaves, so will be executed the most. Have you considered passing color as a parameter, rather than calculating it from the board like that on every single leaf?

Comment: Tried it, same results. Makes sense since the calculation of color involves simply a getter method.

Comment: Well, 3 method calls, the ?: operation, and an assignment, but ok. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: It's ok, thanks anyway. I forgot to mention that the bulk of the computation time lies in the board evaluation function.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I should have posted my full code for the root calls as well -- didn't realise I wasn't passing in the new value for beta. Alpha/beta was actually being updated in the root method for separate min-max.

Updated root method for Negamax:

```
Move bestMove = null;
int bestVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;

for (Move move : MoveSorter.simpleSort(currBoard.getCurrPlayer().getLegalMoves())) {
    MoveTransition transition = currBoard.getCurrPlayer().makeMove(move);
    if (transition.getMoveStatus().isAllowed()) {
        int val = -alphaBeta(transition.getNextBoard(), searchDepth - 1, Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1, -bestVal);
        if (val > bestVal) {
            bestVal = val;
            bestMove = move;
        }
    }
}

return bestMove;
```

Apologies for the lack of information provided in my question -- I didn't expect the bug to be there.

Comment: Yeah, ideally you shouldn't be duplicating all that code just for a "root loop". But then your main function would have to return both a bestMove and a bestVal everywhere,  slowing it down. Tradeoffs.

Comment: I.e. the root call "should" look something like `best = alphaBeta(currBoard, searchDepth, Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE); return best.Move;`.